# Importing Java symbols into a MATLAB user-defined class

Tags: java, matlab

I've got a Java package (let's call it `foo`) that I am using in some MATLAB code. I've been experimenting with organizing that code into a MATLAB-style class, but have found that I have to explicitly call `import foo.*` in any method that uses any of the Java functions. It's not a huge inconvenience or anything, but I can't help but wonder if there's a less clumsy option.